# How to activate search box in PHP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

I've been trying to activate the search box but it's not working, when I try to type something in it I can't see what I typed (nothing appear on it) and I can't see any results of my search, When I try to type a product name and press enter to see my search result it takes me to the view product page which is correct but nothing appear in that page (no results of).

This is the JavaScript code I wrote:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
    
    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the search box in PHP:

```
 <div class="span4" >
                <div class="search-box">
                    <form method="POST" class="search_form" action="allProducts.php">
                        
                        <input type="text"  Placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" name="pro">
                        <div class ="result"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                            </div>
```

Also this is the view product page where i want to see my search result in:

```
  <section class="main-content">          
                        <ul class="thumbnails listing-products">
<?php
                                             try{
                                                
                                               if (isset($_POST["pro"])){
                                                $cat=$_POST["pro"];
                                            require ("connection.php");
                                            $sql2=" SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_category LIKE '%".$cat."%' ";
                                            $result=$db->query($sql2);
                                                
                                         
                                            foreach($result as $r){
                                            
                                            ?>                                          
                                                <li class="span3">
                                                    <div class="product-box">
                                                        <span class="sale_tag"></span>
                                                        <p><a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>" ><img src="images/<?php echo $r['item_photo'];?>" alt="" /></a></p>
                                                        <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>" class="title"><?php echo $r['item_name'];?></a><br/>
                                                        <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>"><?php echo $r['item_brand'];?></a>
                                                        <p class="price"><?php echo $r['item_price'];?>BHD</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    } ?>
                                                       
                                            <?php
                                    $db=NULL;
                                             }}
                            catch (PDOException $ex){ 
                                die($ex->getMessage());
                            }
                                        ?>                              
            </ul>
            </section>
```

And this is my database table in PhpMyAdmin:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot see what you type? Try to inspect it using developer tools of your browser maybe you set the text color to white.

Comment: yes but the most important thing is the search result do you see any problem in my code?

Comment: I will add an answer I think there is a problem with your code on searching.

Answer (score 0):

In your form search text input you use name `pro` but in the product page you use `$_GET["cat"]` which is wrong. You should use `$_POST["pro"]` and on searching you should use condition `LIKE` on searching you can try this one.

```
<section class="main-content">          
   <ul class="thumbnails listing-products">
    <?php
       try{
          if (isset($_POST["pro"])){
            $cat=$_POST["pro"];
            require ("connection.php");
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_category LIKE '%".$cat."%'";
            $result=$db->query($sql2);
            foreach($result as $r){
    ?>                                          
            <li class="span3">
            <div class="product-box">
               <span class="sale_tag"></span>
               <p><a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>" ><img src="images/<?php echo $r['item_photo'];?>" alt="" /></a></p>
                  <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>" class="title"><?php echo $r['item_name'];?></a><br/>
                  <a href="product_detail.php?iid=<?php echo $r['item_id'];?>"><?php echo $r['item_brand'];?></a>
                <p class="price"><?php echo $r['item_price'];?>BHD</p>
             </div>
             </li>
    <?php } ?>
   </ul>   
   
   <?php
      $db=NULL;
      }}
      catch (PDOException $ex){ 
          die($ex->getMessage());
      }
   ?>                              
</section>
```

Comment: You can also check if directly on your phpadmin you can just copy your query and try it directly on SQL if it has results.

Comment: I used what you did and I made some small changes and it worked, but not all items, when i search about item 'cake' and 'mariyam' it doesn't show any results, it shows results only when i search about 'xxxxx' item (2 results appear)  and they're correct results. + i added the table above please have a look.

Comment: Ok just play some of your queries so that you can get accurate results :)